# asynchronous retry using IExecutorService

Tags: java, asynchronous, hazelcast

I'm trying to figure out a way to implement an asynchronous retry mechanism using **Hazelcast** IExecutorService without recursive calls:

The recursive solution looks like that:

```
Callable task = ...

private sendToExecutor(){ 

  Future future = submitToExecutorService(task);

  ((ICompletableFuture<ActionReply>) future).andThen(callback);
}
```

The callback is an ExecutionCallback:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(ActionReply response) {
     // normal stuff
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

    // re-send if possible
    if(numRetries < max_retries){ 
        sendToExecutor();
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to find a nice solution that does not involve the recursion. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper class that implements `Future` and implement the `get` method which should catch `RetryableHazelcastException`. Note that you need have a limit on number of retries. If it crosses that limit means, there some major problem with your cluster.

```
public class RetryableFuture implements Future {
    //Implement other methods.

    @Override
    public Object get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        try{
            //get operation on future object
        }catch(ExecutionException e){
            if(e.getCause() instanceof RetryableHazelcastException){
                //Log some warnings and submit the task back to Executors
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Not all exceptions are retryable
        }finally {
            //Close any kind of resources.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i don't seem to understand, could you please articulate it a bit more? Thanks!